# Kubernetes pod to GCP Compute Engine VM communication

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

How can I connect to VM's running in GCP compute engine from Kubernetes pod? I have setup a proxy server in Compute Engine and I need to use that from within pods.

This communication needs to be using internal IP. I have allowed firewall rules to allow all internal IP.

Any suggestions on how to connect from pods to gcp vm's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an internal load balancer in GCP and connect VM **or** you can use the VPC peering if in a different network.

- If your GKE and VM are in the same network you can use the internal IP of your VM to connect with.

From inside of POD you can send **curl** requests to the VM over internal IP.

**OR**

- If your GKE and GCP VM both are in the different networks you can use the VPC peering to connect both networks and use the internal IP of VM from POD.